# Conflicting provider version contraints in Terraform tutorial

Tags: terraform

I’m following the [Target Resources](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/resource-targeting?in=terraform/cli) tutorial and I get the following failure when I run the `terraform init` setup step:

```
│ Error: Failed to query available provider packages
│
│ Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider hashicorp/aws: locked provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws 3.39.0 does not match configured version
│ constraint ~> 3.39.0, >= 3.50.0; must use terraform init -upgrade to allow selection of new versions
```

Running `terraform init -upgrade` results in this similar error message:

```
│ Error: Failed to query available provider packages
│
│ Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider hashicorp/aws: no available releases match the given constraints ~> 3.39.0, >= 3.50.0
```

It looks like the ~>3.39.0 version specified in `./main.tf` conflicts with the >=3.5.0 contraint from the s3_bucket module (`.terraform/modules/s3_bucket/versions.tf`).

I’ve tried cloning a clean version of the tutorial repository and keep running into this error. Is this a problem with my local configuration or with the tutorial code? If the latter, what’s the best way to move past this? Should I adjust one of the constraints manually to resolve the conflict?

I am using a much newer version of the Terraform CLI (v1.0.7) where the tutorial text requires v0.14 and up. I haven't gotten a chance to downgrade and test again, but that would be interesting to see.

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a bug in the `main.tf` located in the root module config in the repository for that tutorial. The bug is located [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/learn-terraform-resource-targeting/blob/main/main.tf#L5). The line should be modified and the resulting argument object appear like:

```
aws = {
  source  = "hashicorp/aws"
  version = "~> 3.39"
}
```

That will lock the version to the range `>= 3.39.0 < 4.0.0`, which is almost certainly the config's original intent. You can read more about the syntax behind the provider version specifications in the [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/providers/requirements.html#best-practices-for-provider-versions).